# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with web view

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a class called productView.swift with this command below that loads a website inside a webView:

```
 webView.delegate = self

 func loadRequest(){
   webView?.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!))
 }
```

This code works very well when I call him! The problem is that I have a UITableView class that have a menu (Side bar menu) when I select a row in that table I call that function `loadRequest()` with this code inside my UITableView class:

```
productView().loadMenuItem()
```

I receive the response in my productView class, but when he try to load the URL I receive the following message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: When you talk about class called `productView` **(class name should start with uppercase letter!)**, you mean a `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **class name should start with uppercase letter!**

So, the problem is you are calling a `ViewController` like this:

```
productView()
```

This creates a new instance of the class (ViewController), but that's not the way to initialize a controller, because doing so it creates an empty instance of the controller. Instead you have to look for it in the storyboard:

```
if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProductViewController")
    controller.methodFromController()
}
```

Then you call your function.

I suggest you check for possible errors by using optional wrapping:

```
func loadRequest() {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com"), let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url), webView = self.webView {
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is happening inside loadMenuItem() has a nil value when you're trying to convert it to an NSURL. Try something like this instead:

```
func loadMenuItem() {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://MenuItemURLString),
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url) {
        webView?.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

This should at least tell you where your nil optional is